# taking text from a JTextField and placing it into a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jtextarea

This is my Main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Program p = new Program();
        }

}
```

Here is my Program class

```
public class Program {

    public Program(){
        //System.out.println("Let's begin...");

        TextEditor textEditor = new TextEditor();
        textEditor.setVisible(true);
        textEditor.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    }
}
```

Here is my TextEditor class. In this class is where I have a JFrame that has a text field in which I would like the results of the fahrenheit to celcus conversion found in my Calculator class to be placed.

```
public class TextEditor extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JTextArea textArea;

public TextEditor(){
    super("TextMe");
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    loadMenuBar();
    loadToolBar();
    loadTextArea();
    this.pack();
}

private void loadTextArea() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
    this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textArea);
}

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
}   loadCalculator()
private void loadCalculator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
    calculator.setVisible(true);
    calculator.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

    textArea.setText(String.valueOf(c.fahrenheit));

}
```

Here is my Calculator class which extends JFrame and implements ActionListener. In here is where a JFrame comes up with a JButton and a JTextField next to it. When the user enters a number into the text field, it does a calculation and converts Fahrenheit to Celsius. Once that is done, I would like the result to show up on the JTextArea from the TextEditor Class.

```
public class Calculator extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
JButton fToCButton;
JTextField fToC;
double fahrenheit;
TextEditor a = new TextEditor();

public Calculator(){
            super("Unit Converter");
            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            fToC = new JTextField(5);

fToCButton = new JButton("Ferenheit To Celcius");
            fToCButton.addActionListener(this);

add(fToCButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
            add(fToC);
this.pack()

@Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(e.getSource() == fToCButton){
                degreeConversion();
            }
        }

        private void degreeConversion() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            double conversion = Double.parseDouble(fToC.getText());
            fahrenheit = (((conversion -32) * 5) / 9);
            a.textArea.setText(String.valueOf(fahrenheit));
            System.out.println(fahrenheit);
        }


 }
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Why dont u try to pass the `string` as a parameter. `String s = field.getText(); pass(s);` Where pass is method of another class.

Comment: Thank You @AndrewThompson, I did reduce my original code to just the areas that I am having issues with, which is what I posted. This is probably about 1/4 of my original code for my full program.

Comment: I am still very new to programming, but i thought passing strings as paramaters was more for c# or c++.

Comment: An MCVE needs to be a single source file.  To do that (and allow it to compile) 1) Change `public class TextEditor` to `class TextEditor` 2) Paste it into the end of the other source 3) Add the imports needed to compile them & 4) Provide a `main(String[])` to run it.

Comment: I know it seems like many classes but our professor asked us to do our project this way. Seems like it's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andrew Thompson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/418556/andrew-thompson) already indicated, make sure your code at least compiles and has a main method. The `TextEditor` class you provided is missing the `loadMenuBar` & `loadToolBar` methods, the `actionPerformed` & `loadCalculator` methods are sort of merged together, and a main method is missing in both classes. Please formulate your question as best as you can to get good answers.

I think the reason that the result of the conversion does not show up is that the `TextEditor` and `Calculator` objects are not connected to each other. In the `Calculator.degreeConversion` method you try to pass the result to a `TextEditor` object, but this object is created by the calculator itself (see the field declaration) and this text editor is not visible. This could be solved by passing a reference of the text editor to the calculator constructor.

In code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


/**
 * TextEditor class.
 */
public class TextEditorVersion2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JTextArea textArea;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final TextEditorVersion2 textEditor = new TextEditorVersion2();
        textEditor.setVisible(true);
        final CalculatorVersion2 calculatorVersion2 = new CalculatorVersion2(textEditor);
        calculatorVersion2.setVisible(true);
    }

    public TextEditorVersion2(){
        super("TextMe");
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // Freek: these methods are missing.
        //loadMenuBar();
        //loadToolBar();
        // Freek: these methods are missing.
        loadTextArea();
        this.pack();
    }

    private void loadTextArea() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
        this.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, textArea);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    }

    private void loadCalculator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CalculatorVersion2 c = new CalculatorVersion2(this);
        CalculatorVersion2 calculatorVersion2 = new CalculatorVersion2(this);
        calculatorVersion2.setVisible(true);
        calculatorVersion2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);

        textArea.setText(String.valueOf(c.fahrenheit));
    }
}


/**
 * Calculator class.
 */
class CalculatorVersion2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton fToCButton;
    JTextField fToC;
    double fahrenheit;
    TextEditorVersion2 a;

    public CalculatorVersion2(final TextEditorVersion2 textEditor) {
        super("Unit Converter");
        this.a = textEditor;
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        fToC = new JTextField(5);

        fToCButton = new JButton("Ferenheit To Celcius");
        fToCButton.addActionListener(this);

        add(fToCButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(fToC);
        this.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getSource() == fToCButton){
            degreeConversion();
        }
    }

    private void degreeConversion() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double conversion = Double.parseDouble(fToC.getText());
        fahrenheit = (((conversion -32) * 5) / 9);
        a.textArea.setText(String.valueOf(fahrenheit));
        System.out.println(fahrenheit);
    }
}
```